# Solving set of Equations with Products

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $$M:=\{(x,y,z)^T\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+2yz=3\wedge x^2+y^2+yz = z^2+5\}$$
For some vector $(x_0,y_0,z_0)^T\in M, y_0z_0\ne0$ I must show there exists an open space $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ around $x_0$, as well as continuously differentiable functions $g,h: U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $g(x_0)=y_0$, $h(x_0)=z_0$ and $(x,g(x),h(x))^T\in M 
\quad\forall x \in U$

I believe this can be achieved by solving the equations given to define M to simply calculate the functions.

I'm stuck after multiple rounds of solving for and inserting (solve fist equation for $y$, insert into the second equation to get rid of $yz$, etc.), as I keep hitting products (e.g. $x^2y^2$). Is this even the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you fix the value of $x$, the two equations describe a pair of hyperbolas which, after rearranging a bit, are $$yz = \frac12(3-x^2) \\ y^2+yz-z^2=5-x^2.$$ Since $y_0z_0\ne0$, there is a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0,z_0)^T$ in which neither $y$ nor $z$ is zero, so you can solve the first equation for either $y$ or $z$ and substitute into the second. Solving for $z$ produces $$y^2+\frac12(3-x^2)-\left({3-x^2\over 2y}\right)^2=5-x^2.$$ Multiplying through by $y^2$ (again valid because $y\ne0$) and rearranging will give you a quadratic equation in $y^2$ that I expect you know how to solve. There will be four possible solutions, but I don’t think there’s a way to choose which of the four unwieldy-looking expressions is the correct one for an arbitrary element of $M$. For $z$, you can either go through the same process, or substitute directly into the expression you got for $z$ while solving for $y$. I’d recommend the latter since it’s less work and will help you pair up the expressions for $y$ and $z$ correctly.

Comment: Thank you. The problem says there is an open neighborhood $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and the functions $g,h$ are only defined on U. As I keep hitting things like $\sqrt{8+z^2}$ in solving the equations directly, do you see any way that restricting the functions to U could simplify the problem?

Comment: @RubenKruepper $U$ is determined by your solution. The regions in which the solution is valid will determine an appropriate choice for $U$, not the other way around.

Comment: Could the implicit function theorem be used for this problem? I stumbled across it by chance, and it seems the question "wants" to be answered that way.

Comment: I will open a new question but thank you for the algebra, it certainly answered the question I asked!

Comment: @RubenKruepper Good observation! This exercise is basically asking you to verify the theorem for this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: It is $$3=z^2+5$$ since the left-hand sides are equal! So there no solutions.
In the corrected case:
We get $$yz=z^2+5-x^2-y^2$$ so
$$x^2+2(z^2+5-x^2-y^2)=3$$
Simplifying
$$x^2+2y^2=7+2z^2$$
Ok, you can write $$x^2+y^2+2yz=3+y^2$$
$$x^2+y^2+yz=z^2+5$$ so get
$$3+y^2-yz=z^2+5$$
so you will obtain $y$ as a function of $z$

Comment: I am terribly sorry I mistyped!

Comment: Thank you, but when I try to solve the equation for either $z$ dependant on $x$ or $y$ dependant on $x$, I get stuck with $x^2z^2$ terms again, can you give me another hint, please?

Comment: How can I solve for $z$ or $y$ when there is the term $-yz$? Or is it just not possible?

Comment: You can use the quadratic formula.

Comment: $$y_1=z/2+1/2\,\sqrt {5\,{z}^{2}+8}$$ or $$y_2=z/2-1/2\,\sqrt {5\,{z}^{2}+8}$$